# PackageManagement\Install-Module from private feed fails with The file '....\_rels\.rels' already exsists

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, package-management

Getting the following error message when trying to install a module from our private proget nuget feed.  We have published and installed many previous versions of this package from the proget feed before.  The only thing in the psd1 file that has changed is the version number.  The binaries have changed quite a bit, but it all works when running the module manually.

Anybody got any ideas?

```
>     PackageManagement\Install-Package : Package '....' failed to be installed because: The file
>     'C:\Users\....\Local\Temp\3\h5gnpefn\_rels\.rels' already exists.
>     At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:2052
> char:20
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this is all very strange, while I don't know why this was causing a problem the file _rels.rels was a part of the module that I published and should not have been included in the module.

After deleting this folder/file the issue went away.

Very strange.